# como puedo activar IntelliSense en SQL Server 2014 cuando me conecto a un servidor en azure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Al estar conectado de manera local y escribir una consulta el IntelliSense funciona normalmente, genera las ayudas de autocompletado. Pero al conectarme a una instancia de bd de Microsoft Azure el IntelliSense deja de funcionar .
Encontre un post en stackoverflow ingles, donde recomiendan reemplazar el intellisence por defecto por otro de pago.
Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

[Post en StackOverflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342517/are-there-any-ssms-alternatives-that-give-autocompletion-for-sql-azure)

[image: Conectado en Microsoft Azure]
[image: Conectado de manera Local]

Answer (score 2):

Actualiza el Management Studio a la versión 17.2 que ya soporta el Intellisense.

Fuente [SQL Server Management Studio - Changelog (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms#downloadssdtmediadownloadpng-ssms-172httpsgomicrosoftcomfwlinklinkid849819)

Acá un extracto del cambio relevante:

> IntelliSense is now supported for Azure SQL Database
>   https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3100677/ssms-2016-would-be-nice-to-have-intellisense-on-azure-sql-databases

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/58947)

Comment: @toledano, en realidad esta es una respuesta correcta y acabo de probar que funciona

Comment: Tienes razón, debí reportarla como respuesta de baja calidad. No sé que pasó.

Comment: Como comentario para @Alvaro: La última versión del SSMS es gratuita e independiente del motor de SQL Server y la puedes descargar aquí: [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Comment: Al parecer versiones anteriores a la 17.x del SSMS no tienen soporte nativo para IntelliSense con Azure. Cabe recalcar que existen plugins externos que pueden instalarse en la 2014 y que podrían funcionar,  pero no es lo que buscaba. Aunque mi pregunta era para la version 2014 , al Instalar la version 17 funciono correctamente y resolvio el problema.
Gracias por su ayuda.